# Can I create this XML file with lxml?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm trying to generate an xml that looks exactly like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XML type="formats" version="4">
  <format type="format" uid="BEAUTY:MasterBeauty">
    <type>video</type>
    <channelsDepth type="uint">16</channelsDepth>
    <channelsEncoding type="string">Float</channelsEncoding>
    <channelsEndianess type="string">Little Endian</channelsEndianess>
    <fieldDominance type="int">2</fieldDominance>
    <height type="uint">1080</height>
    <nbChannels type="uint">4</nbChannels>
    <pixelLayout type="string">ABGR</pixelLayout>
    <pixelRatio type="float">1</pixelRatio>
    <rowOrdering type="string">up</rowOrdering>
    <width type="uint">1920</width>
  </format>
</XML>
```

It's part of a VFX nodal workflow script ensemble and this file is part of a "read media" node.
I've spent the whole week looking at many different things but can't find anything close to this. I picked lxml for the pretty print thing. I was able to generate a bunch of other simpler (to me) xml files but for this one, I gotta say … i'm lost. Complete fail so far! 
Could someone kindly shed a light on this please?

MY QUESTIONS:
- is lxml appropriate for this?
- if no, what is a better choice? (i did look for ElementTree example, no luck!)
- if yes, where do i start? Could someone share a piece a code to get me started?

What i could create so far was things like this one:

```
import os, sys
import lxml.etree
import lxml.builder as lb
from lxml import etree 

E = lxml.builder.ElementMaker()
Setup = E.Setup
Base = E.Base
Version = E.Version
Note = E.Note
Expanded = E.Expanded
ScrollBar = E.ScrollBar
Frames = E.Frames
Current_Time = E.Current_Time
Input_DataType = E.Input_DataType
ClampMode = E.ClampMode
AdapDegrad = E.AdapDegrad
UsedAsTransition = E.UsedAsTransition
State = E.State


root_node = Setup(
        Base(
            Version('12.030000'),
            Note(''),
            Expanded('False'),
            ScrollBar('0'),
            Frames('0'),
            Current_Time('1'),
            Input_DataType('3'),
            ClampMode('0'),
            AdapDegrad('False'),
            UsedAsTransition('False')
            ),
        State(),
                  )
print lxml.etree.tostring(root_node, pretty_print=True)

str = etree.tostring(root_node, pretty_print=True)

myXMLfile = open('/Users/stefan/XenDRIVE/___DEV/PYTHON/Create_xlm/create_Batch_xml_setups/result/xml_result/root.root_node.xml', 'w')
myXMLfile.write(str)
myXMLfile.close()
```

Hope those are "acceptable" questions.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make the `format` node and then add it to the root `XML` node.

Example code (follow it to create more nodes):

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.builder import ElementMaker

E = ElementMaker()

format = E.format(
    E.type("video"),
    E.channelsDepth("16", type="uint"),
    # create more elements here        

    type="format",
    uid="BEAUTY:MasterBeauty"
)
root = E.XML(
    format,

    type="formats",
    version="4"
)

print(etree.tostring(root, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8', pretty_print=True))
```

Prints:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<XML version="4" type="formats">
  <format type="format" uid="BEAUTY:MasterBeauty">
    <type>video</type>
    <channelsDepth type="uint">16</channelsDepth>
  </format>
</XML>
```

Comment: Oh Yes! This is precisely what i was asking for! A few minutes, 1 answer and boom, right on … vs 1 week of getting lost! Thank you so much @alecxe!!! right now, i'm joyfully crying and repeating your name again and again :)